# Sending data from Angular but not getting it to backend

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

Sending data from Angular but getting null at backend,Here is my code for reference

Registration component from Angular

```
 addnewuser(name: any,pass: any,phnnumb: any,address: any){
   const userId=0;
   const registrationDate= new Date().toISOString();
  const status="ACTIVE";
  const addressId=0;
    this.user=new UserMaster(userId,name,pass,phnnumb,registrationDate,status);
    this.userAddress= new UserAddress(addressId,this.user,address);
    this.userrequest= new UserRequest(this.user,this.userAddress);
    console.log(this.user);
    console.log(this.userAddress);
    console.log(this.userrequest);
    
    this.myservice.createUser(this.userrequest).subscribe(result=>{console.log(result)});
   }
```

My Service class of Angular

```
 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  createUser(userrequest:UserRequest){
   // console.log(this.userrequest);
    return this.http.post<UserRequest>("http://localhost:10003/creatUser",userrequest);
  }
```

My FrontController in spring

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class FrontController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProdcomService ps;
    
    @PostMapping("creatUser")
    public UserMaster creatUser(@ Valid @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
        try {
            System.out.println(userRequest);
            UserMaster userMaster= userRequest.getUserMaster();
            UserAddresses userAddresses=userRequest.getUserAddresses();
            
               if (userMaster == null || userAddresses == null) {
                    System.out.println("Received null objects in the request.");
                    return null;  
                }
               

                System.out.println("Received uMaster: " + userMaster);
                System.out.println("Received userAddresses: " + userAddresses);
        
            UserMaster uMaster= ps.creatuserService(userMaster);
            userAddresses.setUser(uMaster);
             ps.createaddressService(userAddresses);
             return uMaster;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception6
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        
    }
```

My entity Class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserMaster")
public class UserMaster {
    
    public enum UserStatus {
        ACTIVE,
        INACTIVE,
        PENDING_APPROVAL,
        BLOCKED
    }
    
     @Id
      //  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @SequenceGenerator(name = "mygenerator", sequenceName = "mysequence", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mygenerator")
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Long userId;

        @Column(name = "user_name")
        private String userName;

        @Column(name = "user_password")
        @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&-+=()])(?=\\S+$).{8,20}$",message = "password should consist of uppercase,lowercase,number,special characer and minimum of 8 character and atmost 20 character long")
        private String userPassword;

        @Column(name = "phone_number")
        @Size(min = 10,max = 10,message = "phone number should of only 10 digit")
        @NotNull(message = "phone number can not be null")
        private String phoneNumber;

        @Column(name = "registration_date")
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
        private Date registrationDate;
        
        @Column(name = "status")
        private UserStatus status;
        
//      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//      List<UserAddresses> addresses;
```

My useraddress entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserAddresse")
public class UserAddresses {

    @Id
   // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mygenerator", sequenceName = "addsequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mygenerator")
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private Long addressId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserMaster user;

    @Column(name = "full_address")
    private String fullAddress;

    public Long getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(Long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }
```

My Service class at Backend:

````
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProdcomServiceImp implements ProdcomService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProdcomJpaRespository pr;
    @Autowired
    private ProdcomAddressRepository pa;

    @Override
    public UserMaster creatuserService(UserMaster uMaster) {
        UserMaster userMaster= pr.save(uMaster);
        
        return userMaster;
    }
    ```
````

---

---

---

I am trying send the data from angular but receiving null at backend, but if sending from swagger getting data at the backend.I am sending two objects one is usermaster and one is useraddres, one usermaster can have multiple addresses,sending two objects in single bundle that is userrequest. My format of sending data from Angular is what i got from console is:

```
userMaster
: 
UserMaster
phoneNumber
: 
"9560654651"
registrationDate
: 
"2023-10-09T00:48:52.001Z"
status
: 
"ACTIVE"
userId
: 
0
userName
: 
"Ramit"
userPassword
: 
"Ramit@1234"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
useraddress
: 
UserAddress
addressId
: 
0
fullAddress
: 
"Spr"
user
: 
UserMaster
phoneNumber
: 
"9560654651"
registrationDate
: 
"2023-10-09T00:48:52.001Z"
status
: 
"ACTIVE"
userId
: 
0
userName
: 
"Ramit"
userPassword
: 
"Ramit@1234"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

The data I am sending from swagger is:

````
{
  "userMaster": {
    "userId": 0,
    "userName": "string",
    "userPassword": "string",
    "phoneNumber": "string",
    "registrationDate": "2023-10-09T01:43:32.188Z",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  "userAddresses": {
    "addressId": 0,
    "user": {
      "userId": 0,
      "userName": "string",
      "userPassword": "string",
      "phoneNumber": "string",
      "registrationDate": "2023-10-09T01:43:32.188Z",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "fullAddress": "string"
  }
}```
According to me, there is a mismatch between data from angular and data at backend, but don't what is the error and how to correct it.
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Try to send only one data from your service(client) then check on your controller(backend) whether you are getting it or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> According to me, there is a mismatch between data from angular and data at backend, but don't what is the error and how to correct it.

A mismatch in the data between the client and the server will result in a BAD_REQUEST exception.

The error is in the creation of the UserRequest that is being sent to the back end. Sharing the User* models and the related code might be helpful.